# Query in sql server to sort data which has both numbers and alphabets

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my tables have values like this..

```
Year 1
Year 9
Year 8
Year 4
Kindy [can be any word without numbers]
Pre-School [can be any word without numbers]
Year 8
Year 22
Year 15....
```

How can I sort Them in alphabetically first and then by numerically in ascending order like this..

```
Kindy 
Pre-School
Year 1
Year 4
Year 8
Year 9
Year 15
Year 22
```

I have tried the following..

```
SELECT  YearLevel FROM Student 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN YearLevel NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 0
ELSE CAST(RIGHT(YearLevel, LEN(YearLevel) - 5) AS int)
END
```

But the problem is I need distinct records only..

Comment: is the problem sorting or arriving at unique records? Arriving at the wanted unique records should come first. have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT` Please note `SELECT DISTINCT` works across the entire row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column with digits always has the `Year [digits]` format, you can try this

```
SELECT YearLevel FROM student
GROUP BY YearLevel 
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN YearLevel LIKE 'Year%'
        THEN 'Year' + CONVERT(varchar,LEN(YearLevel)) + YearLevel
        ELSE YearLevel
    END)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1919c/3

While this may work I recommend adding an integer column with the sorting order.

Comment: I have marked this answer becoz... it brings distinct values :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
        astring
from table1
order by 
        case when left(astring,5) = 'Year ' then 2
           else 1 end
      , case when left(astring,5) = 'Year ' then right(replace(astring,'Year ','00000000'),3)
           else astring end
      , astring
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70cae/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    YourTable
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(INT, STUFF(Col, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Col)-1, '')), 
    LEFT(Col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Col+'1')-2)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/693e3/1)

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful

```
;WITH cte_Student (YearLevel) as
(SELECT 'Kindy ' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year 9' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year 4' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pre-School' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year 1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year 15' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year 8' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year 22')
SELECT YearLevel
FROM cte_Student
ORDER BY
         CASE
         WHEN LEFT(YearLevel, 5) = 'Year ' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(YearLevel, 5, LEN(YearLevel)) AS INT)
         ELSE 0
         END;
```